# dojo registry.byId is returning null in a function called by an event

Tags: javascript, dojo

I've inherited a project that is using Dojo and am getting a really strange error.

A menu is built using the results from a ajax call

```
mi = new dijit.MenuItem({ label:"Snapshot " + ro.name, onClick:onShowSnapshot });
mi.data = ro.auid;
snap_show.addChild(mi);
```

The function gets called

```
function onShowSnapshot(e) {
        var mi = registry.byId(e.target.id);
        current_snapshot = mi.data;
        showSnapshot();
}
```

but mi is null though the id is correct, its like it cant find the widget

Dojo version is 1.10

Most things in this page work, but the events from the menus always produce this error.

Answer (score 0):

Not knowing the rest of your code, guessing the setup and testing via outputting the 'e' object to the console... I think you will get your desired result if you amend a line in your code to the following:

```
var mi = registry.byId(e.target.parentNode.id);
```

A working example can be seen here, where the 'data' is output to the console after the onclick event:

https://jsfiddle.net/538g8aet/6/

Comment: Thanks, in the end I went for an anonymous function as well, solved the whole problem.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the target you are getting in the handler is some node within the MenuItem, but not the .domNode of the menu item itself. I see the node containing the label of the menu item.

What you could also do is use [registry](http://dojotoolkit.org/api/1.10/dijit/registry.html).getEnclosingWidget to get to the widget. This might be handy if you don't want `n` functions to handle all of the menu items.

```
function onShowSnapshot(e) {
        var mi = registry.getEnclosingWidget(e.target);
        current_snapshot = mi.data;
        showSnapshot();
}
```